# How can I insert a record from a form script into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

//How can the following code be amended so that the values inserted into my form can be inserted into my mysql database? I can connect to my database just fine, my database is called images and the table is called persons.

```
     //This is my insert.php file

        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","anble","images");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            // escape variables for security
            $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["FirstName"]);
            $LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["LastName"]);
            $Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Age']);

            $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, LastName, Age);
            VALUES ($FirstName, $LastName, $Age)";

            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            echo "1 record added";

            mysqli_close($con);
            ?> 

        // This is my form file

        <html>
        <body>

        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Firstname: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="FirstName">
        Lastname: <input name="LastName" type="text" value="LastName">
        Age: <input name="Age" type="text" value="Age">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html> 



   // This is the error
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp \htdocs\check_php\insert.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\check_php\insert.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\check_php\insert.php on line 12
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; VALUES (, , )' at line 1
```

Comment: Look up `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in the PHP manual and look at the parameters it expects. This is very basic stuff.

Comment: So? The error messages tell you precisely what's wrong. A look at the manual will give you the information to fix it.

Comment: "I am 15 yrs old"..That's my excuse. What's yours? You just commented and replied to " I am 15yrs old" thanks for wasting not only my time but the time of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cahnge :

```
  // escape variables for security
        $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["FirstName"]);
        $LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["LastName"]);
        $Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Age']);
```

to:

```
  // escape variables for security
        $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["FirstName"]);
        $LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,,$_POST["LastName"]);
        $Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Age']);
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` need two parameters to pass
1)connection

2)escapestring

you have passed only escapestring, you need provide link identifier in `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

<kbd>[see doc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)</kbd>

you also need to add quotes in string variable inside query.
Change:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, LastName, Age);
            VALUES ($FirstName, $LastName, $Age)";
```

to:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, LastName, Age)
            VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Age')";
```

Comment: INow this error is present- Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; VALUES (Andrew, Brin, 15)' at line 1

Comment: `$Firstname` and `$Lastname` are string variables. They should be enclosed in single quotes ' when used in queries.

Comment: try my updated answer and also try to understand what was the problem in your script @user3553512

Comment: I have exactly what youve got-

Comment: The following error is now present- Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; VALUES ('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age')' at line 1

Comment: now try it. i have changed query and let me know if it works.

Comment: OHh sweet now it works. thank you very much for being patient with me

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

1) `mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects 2 required parameters.

2) `$Firstname` and `$Lastname` are string variables. They should be enclosed in single quotes `'` when used in queries.

```
$FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["FirstName"]);
$LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["LastName"]);
$Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, LastName, Age);
      VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', $Age)";
```